# add android button's on click event in a separate class

Tags: android, android-button

I have a button in android which i have defined in fragment_main.xml as -

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/love_button_text" 
    android:onClick="onLoveButtonClicked"
    />
```

the main_activity xml file is as follows -

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.newa.newapp2.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"         >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
    android:text="@string/a_button" 
    android:onClick="onLoveButtonClicked1"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now as there is a onClick event defined i wanted to define in a separate class file as follows -

```
public class AndroidLove extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
}

public void onLoveButtonClicked1(View view) {       
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anotherText);        
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
}   
  }
```

This compiles fine but at run time throws the error

"**could not find the event listener named onLoveButtonClicked**"

This however is working fine if i write the function in my MainActivity.java

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You should catch the onClick event in the fragment, knowing that you got an instance of the parent activity from onAttach (or jst use GetActivity() if you are sure that it is not null) and define a method in the activity that you call from the fragment. This is if you need to do work in the activity from an event firing from the fragment

Comment: how to write that please i dont know about android. I only have one file that extends ActionBarActivity. I have no idea how to write a Fragment class

Comment: but then how come the code is working fine if i write the event function inside the class which extends ActionBarActivity?

Comment: If you don't know about android, using fragment is a bit too much. What do you need them for ? :/ maybe fragment_main is the parent activity of the fragment ?

Comment: now i have added a button in the activity_main.xml. But still the same problem persists.

Comment: Maybe don't use "onClick" in the xml layout. In the activity onCreate get the Button view the same way that the textview, call "setOnClickListener(this)" on it and make the activity extends onClickListener...

Comment: nope the button does not respond to the onclick event in a seperate file.

Comment: Well this is basically the method below

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous inner class in your fragment class.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly remove this from your xml:

```
android:onClick="onLoveButtonClicked"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello the Button is in your fragment_main.xml file

and you are setting content view in activity_main to  AndroidLove activity.

i think you need to write onLoveButtonClicked() method inside Fragment not in activity.

---

Method name from xml and java file must same.
activity/fragment that set that xml file as content view it must be have same name method with view as params.

Thanx.

Comment: so it should be AndroidLove extends Fragment?

Comment: where you are setting fragment_main.xml file, it is fragment or is it activity?

Comment: The Activity_main.xml contains the Layout for the FragmentActivity and the fragment_main.xml is the Layout for the fragment.

Comment: then you suppose to write onLoveButtonClicked method inside fragment.

Comment: I only have one file that extends ActionBarActivity. I have no idea how to write a Fragment class

Comment: but then how come the code is working fine if i write the event function inside the class which extends ActionBarActivity?

Comment: please make it clear and post little more code.
i think you are in new in android so please learn how to communicate between fragment and activity.thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53863/discussion-between-imtiyaz-and-pradyut-bhattacharya)